# Exacttarget issue in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

i have a data extention in exacttarget which contains campaign field values. And i want to use them in our exacttarget email templete . how to insert data extention value in templete in exacttarget

Answer (score 0):

you can insert using this `%%[Firstname]%%`

Answer (score 0):

You can use personalization string. For ex - %%dataextensionfieldname%%

You can put this string anywhere in your email template and it will pull the data from Data Extension.